# Как оставить в UTF-8 строке только 2х байтовые символы?

Tags: php, yii2, php7

Есть обработчик CSV файлов, с последующей фильтрацией нужных данных по эталонным строкам и дальнейшей записью в MySQL.

Проблема заключается в том что не всегда данные прилетают чистыми и непонятно что искать и удалять для фильтрации.

На данный момент нами применяется такая функция, но она все же пропускает мусор, и база данных при импорте падает с ошибкой 22007, даже с учетом того что кодировка в таблице и соединение `utf8mb4`

```
public function normalizeString($string): string
{
    return trim(mb_strtolower(
        preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9 -\/+]/ui', '', $string)
    ));
}
```

Прикрепляю лог [файл](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/X02DxRuINSoUzQ) в котором проявляется эта ошибка в системе, где видно что это ошибка не связана со смещением столбцов в CVS и не связана с датой.

Исходный [файл](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/pBzAXj79Y-uEtg) CSV

Comment: В первом байте такого символа 3 старших бита `110`. Соответственно, надо оставлять только такой и следующий за ним байт (у него старшие 2 бита д.б. `10`, в противном случае это битый utf-8).

Comment: @avp И, а делать то что, как это реализовать то в PHP?

Comment: Я пишу на Си и асме, наверное знатоки PHP помогут вам. В крайнем случае спросите у них, как сделаны в PHP битовые операции над байтами

Comment: дайте пример входящей строки и нужный итог

Comment: @DrMcSheen как вы себе представляете передачу битой строки на этом сервисе? Могу прикрепить исходный CSV.

Comment: Прикрепите CSV, в котором Точно есть ошибка, поиграюсь)

Comment: В показанном вами файле нет ничего, что я мог бы посчитать «мусором». Вот полный набор символов из этого файла: `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¦«®°±¶»ЁАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяё–—’…№™` и пробел, неразрывный пробел, перенос строки и ` (всего 173 символа)

Comment: А ошибка намекает на то, что скорее всего вы сами где-то накосячили с использованием неправильных кодировок (этот файл в кодировке Windows-1251, если что)

Comment: @andreymal прям я? Или например библиотека чтения/импорта могла такое сделать?

Comment: Такая вероятность конечно есть, но в "зрелых" библиотеках обычно всё в порядке

Comment: @andreymal а если обратить внимание на то что, из 300к записей ломаются только 20-30 шт. в разных прайсах и всегда все падает на букве "Р", и всегда в конце строки?

Comment: @andreymal вы пробовали открывать этот файл в NPP? если открыть его в нотепаде, все норм, если в NPP у него крышу срывает, интересно с чего это бы? Тоже наверное я виноват?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXHz4.png

Comment: `как вы себе представляете передачу битой строки на этом сервисе? Могу прикрепить исходный CSV` В том и дело, что считать битой строкой? `Как оставить в UTF-8 строке только 2х байтовые символы?` Дайте пример такой строки.

Answer (score -1):

В итоге помогло решение [из](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/fixing-broken-utf-8-encoding), функция Encoding::toUTF8 из [библиотеки](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)

В предварительной таблице, если включить HEX режим, видно что в конце строки есть битый непечатаемый и неопределяемый байт (на скрине ниже это видно).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public function storeSingleChunk($attributes, $rows)
{

    foreach ($rows as $row){

        try {

            $this->execute($attributes, $row);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $row[4] = Encoding::toUTF8($row[4]);
            $this->execute($attributes, $row);

            \Yii::error($e->getMessage(), 'error');
        }
    }

}
```

На входе строка `СТАБИЛИЗАТОРА СТОЙКА ПЕ�`

На выходе строка `СТАБИЛИЗАТОРА СТОЙКА ПЕÐ`

Да это не 100% решение, но оно хоть дает не потерять строку из прайса и она пишется в базу.

Comment: В показанном вами файле нет строк с символами � или Ð (и их там в принципе не может быть, потому что в кодировке Windows-1251 не существует таких символов) - это говорит о том, что вы как-то неправильно считываете файл

Comment: Ну и скриншот этой строки из NPP https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A2lH.png

Comment: Ах да, и на показанном вами скриншоте нет никакого "непечатаемого" байта, нарисованная вами стрелочка указывает просто в курсор редактора (и за это я уже наверно минус поставлю, а то вводите в заблуждение других людей)

Comment: @andreymal еще раз повторю что я руками ничего не читаю, это делает библиотека. https://github.com/ruskid/yii2-csv-importer

Comment: @andreymal то что я показываю, это не в файле а в таблице куда вышеупомянутая библиотека пишет данные из файла и в таблице кодировка utf8mb4 так что этот символ там еще как может быть

Comment: В файле этого символа всё ещё нет, а кодировка utf8mb4 поддерживает абсолютно все символы кодировки Windows-1251, что означает, что вы всё ещё неправильно читаете файл. (Упомянутую вами библиотеку сейчас поизучаю)

Comment: (но скриншот-то всё равно показывает в курсор редактора, скриншот показывает абсолютно читаемые символы в кодировке utf-8, так что минус я убирать не буду)

Comment: Посмотрел библиотеку — она [использует](https://github.com/ruskid/yii2-csv-importer/blob/master/CSVReader.php#L71) функцию `fgetcsv`, а в её [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) написано: «Эта функция принимает во внимание настройки локали. К примеру, если LANG установлена в en_US.UTF-8, то **файлы в однобайтовой кодировке будут неправильно прочитаны** этой функцией» — видимо, это как раз ваш случай. То есть, скорее всего, вам **нельзя** читать этот файл этой библиотекой. Ищите другую библиотеку, перекодируйте файл в UTF-8 или меняйте значение LANG

Answer (score -1):

Смените локаль на нужную вам, затем верните ту, что была. Возвращать нужно чтобы не сломать в другом месте. Вот типичный вариант использования:

```
$currentLocale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, '0');
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'ru_RU.utf8');

/** Тут выполняете что вам нужно */

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $currentLocale);
```

Comment: Какое отношение ваш ответ имеет к вопросу? У вопроса заголовок прочитайте, в нем есть вопрос, как удалить из строки используя PHP все символы которые не являются 2х байтовыми, все остальное к вопросу не имеет отношения.